# Removing hh:mm:ss from PHP's strtotime function

Tags: php, highcharts

I'm setting up a HighCharts line graph and the x axis labels won't match up with the data points. The data points roll up to the whole day (no hours). When I add the pointStart, though, I'm getting the unix timestamp for when I run it:

`pointStart: <?php echo strtotime("-1 month -1 day") * 1000; ?>`

Can I say "give me the unix timestamp for a month and a day ago *at midnight*" without complicating things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can :

`<?php echo strtotime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-1 month -1 day"))); ?>`

The `date()` format will remove hours minutes and seconds, then you can re-get your timestamp

Comment: `strtotime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-1 month -1 day")))` returns 1335218400 but I'm expecting 1335139200. Any idea?

Comment: Are you sure ? Actually, I've got the return you're looking forwith this code

Comment: Another way to do it is
`$d = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-1 month -1 day")));
echo $d->getTimestamp();`
But you'll have the same result

Comment: You can check with another date around it : `date('Y-m-d-h-i-s', strtotime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-1 month -1 day"))));`

Comment: Hm, that looks right but the unix timestamp is still off. I'm using XAMPP so it's probably some config setting or something.

Comment: Ah, yea, it definitely works there. I'll figure this out. Thanks for sticking around!